# How to achieve uniform velocity throughout a Translate Animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I have an infinite translate animation applied to an `ImageView`:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -500, 500);
animation.setDuration(4000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
myimage.startAnimation(animation);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

What I have noticed is that the translation process is slower when the image is near the starting and ending point compared to when its near half the distance (middle point).

I guess the velocity for translate animations on android is not uniform.

How do I make the velocity uniform throughout the process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some source-diving to investigate this. First, note that ***if*** a linear interpolator is used to provide `interpolatedTime` values to the `applyTransformation` method of [`TranslateAnimation`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.java), the resulting translation will have constant velocity (because the offsets `dx` and `dy` are linear functions of `interpolatedTime` (lines 149-160)):

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    float dx = mFromXDelta;
    float dy = mFromYDelta;
    if (mFromXDelta != mToXDelta) {
        dx = mFromXDelta + ((mToXDelta - mFromXDelta) * interpolatedTime);
    }
    if (mFromYDelta != mToYDelta) {
        dy = mFromYDelta + ((mToYDelta - mFromYDelta) * interpolatedTime);
    }
    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
}
```

`applyTransformation` is called by the `getTransformation` method of the base [`Animation`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/animation/Animation.java) class (lines 869-870):

```
...
final float interpolatedTime = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(normalizedTime);
applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, outTransformation);
...
```

According to the documentation for the `setInterpolator` method (lines 382-392), `mInterpolator` should default to a linear interpolator:

```
/**
 * Sets the acceleration curve for this animation. Defaults to a linear
 * interpolation.
 *
 * @param i The interpolator which defines the acceleration curve
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#Animation_interpolator
 */
public void setInterpolator(Interpolator i) {
    mInterpolator = i;
}
```

However, this seems to be false: both constructors in the `Animation` class call the `ensureInterpolator` method (lines 803-811):

```
/**
 * Gurantees that this animation has an interpolator. Will use
 * a AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator is nothing else was specified.
 */
protected void ensureInterpolator() {
    if (mInterpolator == null) {
        mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    }
}
```

which suggests that the default interpolator is an `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`. This explains the behavior you describe in your question.

To actually answer your question, then, it would appear that you should amend your code as follows:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -500, 500);
animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animation.setDuration(4000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
myimage.startAnimation(animation);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its been a month only that I have been coding android. I was unaware of this behavior for velocity. Your answer clarifies my doubt and also I got pointers to study further.