# LinearInterpolator is not working correctly

Tags: java, android

```
public void move(Activity activity) {

        moveLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translateX", -500);
        moveLeft.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator);
        moveLeft.setDuration(10000);

        moveLeft.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                Log.d("Interpolator", " My interpolator is " + moveLeft.getInterpolator());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                Log.d("Cancelled", "Animation has been abruptly cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                Log.d("Interpolator", " My interpolator is " + moveLeft.getInterpolator());
            }
        });

                moveLeft.start();
    }
}
```

When I run the `move()` method, I checked for its interpolator both at the start of the animation, and at the end of the animation.

It is literally confirmed to be a `LinearInterpolator` both times I check. But when I run it, it moves as if it has an `AcceleratingInterpolator`. (Starts off really slow, then moves really fast.)

Why isn't it moving at a linear speed if I'm using a `LinearInterpolator`?

Am I using the `ObjectAnimator` incorrectly? Or did I set the interpolator wrong, or do I have to update the layout or what?

**UPDATE :**

I have confirmed the interpolator DOES work. But LinearInterpolator doesn't seem to make it go at a constant rate. I've tested it with the bounce interpolator and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Weird. Presumably you have parentheses in your actual code at this line: `moveLeft.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());` instead of `moveLeft.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator);`. Everything else looks ok though. What happens if you don't set an interpolator at all? By default that should behave linearly (see [line 939 of the source code for `ValueAnimator`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/animation/ValueAnimator.java), from which `ObjectAnimator` inherits).

Comment: Amendment - as I discovered and posted in an earlier answer, the default behavior is actually _not_ linear: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393551/how-to-achieve-uniform-velocity-throughout-a-translate-animation/28393923#28393923 for reference. Not sure it's that useful here though. How are you verifying that the visual animation is definitely speeding up?

Comment: I verified it by looking at it.
There are on-screen blocks and off-screen blocks.
The ones that are on the screen move really slowly at first, then speed up.
The off-screen ones just whizz by really fast.
(I just set their X values manually to test it.)