# setLayoutParams() animation duration doesnt work

Tags: android, animation, transition, duration, layoutparams

I have `LayoutParams` transition with `addRule()`.

My view changes position but duration is instant.

I work on API 15 so I cant use `beginDelayedTransition()`.

```
Animation a = new Animation() {

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layoutFalse.getWidth(), layoutFalse.getHeight());

        positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layoutFalse.requestLayout();
        layoutFalse.setLayoutParams(positionRules);
    }
};

a.setDuration(3000);
layoutFalse.startAnimation(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside this block you do animate nothing.
You just say:

Let this object be in each frame with the contrains I want. No more.

So, I think, If you want to animate something you have to use interpolatedTime like this:
To setup position of view inside RelativeLayout without animation:

```
public void setTopLeftCornerF(float leftMargin, float topMargin) {
    if (this.getLayoutParams() instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = (int)_width;//w();
        params.height = (int)_height;//h();
        params.setMargins((int)leftMargin, (int)topMargin, (int)-leftMargin, (int)-topMargin);
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

to use animation somewhere:

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
    float posX = (float) (mFromX + ((mToX - mFromX) * interpolatedTime));
    float posY = (float) (mFromY + ((mToY - mFromY) * interpolatedTime));

    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(posX,posY);
}
```

Or use `TranslateAnimation` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28393923/1979882)

Answer (score 1):

`applyTransformation()` gets called for each animation frame and the transformation should use the `interpolatedTime` param to calculate transformations for that frame. Your `applyTransformation()` applies the changes unconditionally so the result is the same for all frames.

If you just want to change the layout after a specified time, use `layoutFalse.postDelayed()` to post a `Runnable` that applies the changes after a delay.

Comment: I want for the layout change to last for 3 seconds, not to be be instant

Comment: Then either compute the intermediate steps in your `applyTransformation()`, or use the [Transitions framework](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html)

Comment: How do I do it from `applyTransformation()` thats what I am trying to find out. I have similar transitions on many places in my app and I dont want to  switch it to Transition framework. I would just like to slow it down similar to `beginDelayedTransition()`

Answer (score 0):

Here ,

```
layoutFalse.requestLayout();
layoutFalse.setLayoutParams(positionRules);
```

Your sequence is wrong. Because you should first set `layoutParams` and then call `requestLayout` on your `view`.

It should be as follows

```
layoutFalse.setLayoutParams(positionRules);
layoutFalse.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Layout requests are asynchronous anyway, and `setLayoutParams()` calls `requestLayout()` internally.

Comment: @laalto I agree. `requestLayout` is called automatically. It's in the android sources